# scale_color_brewer (ggplot2) does not colour all the lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

When running this ggplot2 code:

```
ggplot(canine_lower, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=Teeth)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= y~poly(x,4), se=FALSE) + 
  scale_color_grey(start=0.9, end=0.1)
```

I get this plot thanks to the scale_color_grey function:
[image]

There is a gradual grey transition among all groups of teeth (from 1 to 16).
However, I would like to colourize it. For this reason I employed the scale_color_brewer, with partly success. The run code is:

```
ggplot(canine_lower, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=Teeth)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= y~poly(x,4), se=FALSE)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Reds")
```

which offers this unfinished plot:
[image]

As seen above, from 10 to 16 there is no color.

How can I span the color range using this function? Is there any other alternative function?

I must say that I tried with scale_color_gradient with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of colors from `brewer.pal` (in the package `RColorBrewer`), the function `scale_color_brewer` uses to generate the colors, is 9 for sequential palettes. If you look at the help for `brewer.pal` you can check the maximum number of colors for each of the palette types.

You can generate larger palettes in many other ways, such as `scale_color_viridis` as shown by @NateDay, or with the two examples below, but it will be difficult to distinguish so many different colors in the graph.

```
mtcars$rowname=rownames(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars[1:16, ], aes(mpg, hp, color=rowname)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(seq(0,360,length=17)[1:16], 100,65))

ggplot(mtcars[1:16, ], aes(mpg, hp, color=rowname)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(0,100,seq(40,100,length=16)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful answer. Everything understood and the scale_colour_manual function worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `library(viridis)` as an alternative:

```
# a reproducible example
mtcars <- add_rownames(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color = rowname)) +
  geom_point() +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE)
```

[image]

`scale_color_gradient()` is failing you because it is designed to be used to map to continuous values, not discrete ones.